# PHP Receber dados de um CSV via URL

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Bom dia, preciso saber se há possibilidade de fazer `fgetcsv()` usando o temporário de um arquivo `.csv` vindo de uma url.

O motivo de tentar fazer isso é devido ao fato do Chrome não substituir arquivos salvos.

Poderia fazer das formas abaixo:

1. Conseguir salvar pelo PHP ou Javascript sempre substituindo os arquivos.
2. Conseguir ler o arqvuio csv sem salva-lo
   Ou qualquer outra sugestão que satisfaça, pode ser API's.

Eu já uso o php para extrair dados de um arquivo salvo no servidor;
Mas nesse caso teria que substituir o nome do arquivo pela `$url`

```
$url = "http://servidor.com/filtros/%5AD%7A/da:14-02-2017+00%3A00..../output:csv";

if (($base = fopen("arquivo.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
   while (($data = fgetcsv($base, 0, ";")) !== FALSE) {
       $data = array_map("utf8_encode", $data);
       //resultado da extração
   }
}else{
   //retorno do else
}
```

Comment: nao entedi bem, mas ate onde sei o `fopen()` aceita uma URL, so precisa de ter uma configuracao habilitada(nao lembro o nome), seo retorno de `$url` já é um csv acredito que um `fopen($url, 'r')` vai funcioar

Comment: Ele até funciona desta forma, só que exige o login do usuário mesmo com o login já realizado, diretamente pela url funciona.

Comment: Entendi, a sua sessao/login esta salva/associada ao navegador, por isso se colocar direto no navegador funciona. Já quando você passa a URL pelo php, é outra sessao, basicamente é o servidor acessando o site, por isso nao esta logado. O servidor onde tem essa url é seu? É o mesmo servidor que esta chamando o `fopen()`?

Comment: Não, é um servidor externo :( e não me liberam acesso as bases

Comment: Passar os dados de login na url não rola né ?

Comment: Depende de como o servidor gerencia a url de login, mas provavelmente nao. Entao a melhor solucao que tem é fazer um form pra pessoa fazer o upload do arquivo que ela baixa desse servidor.

Comment: É para automatização, tem que salvar o arquivo em local especifico a base vai ler isso a cada 5minutos, por isso a opção de ler o arquivo direto da url seria melhor.

Comment: imaginei que fosse isso, mas se nao tem acesso aos dados diretos, tipo uma api, ou algo parecido, vai ser dificil passar o login e conseguir o csv. Talvez ate consiga, mas tem um porem `e não me liberam acesso as bases` se nao te liberaram o acesso da forma que voce quer pode ate ser que infrinja alguma lei ou coisa parecida.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parte da sua duvida involve a necessidade de fazer um login antes de obter o arquivo, ja que o arquivo em questao esta protegdo por senha.

Na verdade sempre fiquei um pouco intrigado com isso tambem e decidi tentar resolver. Consegui fazer funcionar em uma pagina simples usando cURL.

```
$loginUrl = 'http://url-da-pagina-com-login';
$dataUrl = 'http://url-da-pagina-com-o-csv';

$ch = curl_init ($loginUrl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array(
    'email'=>'email@blablabla.com',
    'password'=>'123',
));

curl_exec($ch);

//basicamente esse é o pulo do gato, voce troca a url, entao ainda continua na mesma sessao
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $dataUrl);
$dataResp = curl_exec($ch);

echo $dataResp;
```

No meu teste exibiu a pagina, então acho que já é um bom ponto de partida. Espero que ajude.

Comment: Neuber muito obrigado pela ajuda, aqui não ficou em branco, o console não exibiu nada. loginUrl: https://servidor.com/login/ dataURl: http://servidor.com/aba/...filtros.../output:csv, coloquei algo assim, os campos de login se chamam; Usuario: name="data[Usuario][email]", id="email-input", Senha: name="data[Usuario][senha]", id="UsuarioSenha"